# Possible to have a branch that is a patch on the master on GitHub?

Tags: git, github

What I mean is, when you create a branch from the master and make changes, you're essentially applying a patch to the master *at the time you checked it out.*

What I want is a branch that will always apply the same diff to the master, so that if master is

```
print('Hi!')
```

and branch is

```
print('Hi!')
print('Bye!')
```

When master is updated to

```
a = 5
b = 3
print(a + b)
```

branch will automatically be

```
a = 5
b = 3
print(a + b)
print('Bye!')
```

Right now the only thing I can think of is using a Webhook to merge the master into the branch each time a commit is made to it, but I've never used Webhooks before and I'm curious if there is a better way.

Comment: It sounds like you might be referring to rebasing. https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing

Comment: Right, I think I (mostly) understand the concept of rebasing (although I am not 100% certain how it differs from merging). But I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to have a branch set to automatically rebase its changes onto the most recent version of master.

Comment: Merging and rebasing tend to end up with the same result. But they do different things to the commit tree which makes them different. See http://think-like-a-git.net